# Serializing/Deserializing Command Object

Tags: c#, serialization, command-pattern

I'm attempting to serialize (and later deserialize) a command object to a string (preferably using the JavaScriptSerializer). My code compiles, however when I serialize my command object it returns an empty Json string, i.e. "{}". The code is shown below.

The aim is to serialize the command object, place it in a queue, then deserialize it later so it can be executed. If the solution can be achieved with .NET 4 then all the better.

**ICommand**

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}
```

**Command Example**

```
public class DispatchForumPostCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly ForumPostEntity _forumPostEntity;

    public DispatchForumPostCommand(ForumPostEntity forumPostEntity)
    {
        _forumPostEntity = forumPostEntity;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _forumPostEntity.Dispatch();
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class ForumPostEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string FromEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public ForumPostEntity()
    {
        PartitionKey = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        RowKey = PartitionKey;
    }

    public void Dispatch()
    {
    }
}
```

**Empty String Example**

```
public void Insert(ICommand command)
{
   // ISSUE: This serialization returns an empty string "{}".
   var commandAsString = command.Serialize();
}
```

**Serialization Extension Method**

```
public static string Serialize(this object obj)
{
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the `ICommand` only contains one method. what serialization result do you expect?

Comment: It is likely (although I have not used the Java serializer) that you need to mark your classes that inherit from `ICommand` with `[Serializable]` and mark each property within that class as an `XmlElement`.

Comment: A string representation of the DispatchForumPostCommand, or another object that inherits from ICommand. After the object is taken off the queue and deserialized I want to call it's Execute command which contains some basic information to help complete the execution.

Comment: Hi @Killercam - I tried that previously but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DispatchForumPostCommand class has no properties to serialize. Add a public property to serialize it. Like this:

```
public class DispatchForumPostCommand : ICommand {
    private readonly ForumPostEntity _forumPostEntity;

    public ForumPostEntity ForumPostEntity { get { return _forumPostEntity; } }

    public DispatchForumPostCommand(ForumPostEntity forumPostEntity) {
        _forumPostEntity = forumPostEntity;
    }

    public void Execute() {
        _forumPostEntity.Dispatch();
    }
}
```

I now get the following as the serialized object (I removed the inheritance of TableEntity for testing purposes):

```
{"ForumPostEntity":{"FromEmailAddress":null,"Message":null}}
```

If you want to deserialize the object as well, then you will need to add the public setter for the property, else the deserializer will not be able to set it.

Comment: Genius. FYI this approach works with the TableEntity inheritance. Thanks @Maarten

Comment: Minor typo I can't edit because it's less than 10 characters "has to properties" => "has no properties"